# Create generator without nested closure?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to create a generator without using a nested closure? I know that currently, you can create a generator via something similar to this pseudo-rust:

```
fn do_thing(i: i32) -> impl Generator<...> {
  || {
    for x in 0..i {
      yield x;
    }
  }
}
```

But is there syntax to do something like the following without macros?

```
fn do_thing(i: i32) -> impl Generator<...> {
  for x in 0..i {
    yield x;
  }
}
```

This seems like an odd design choice since async functions don't need an intermediary closure / async block, and those are implemented with generators under the hood.

Comment: "async blocks are implemented with generators under the hood" is a very Python way of looking at things. As you've noted, Rust doesn't *have* generators and thus cannot implement anything in terms of them. `async` desugars to a `Future` trait implementation in a process detailed [in the async Rust book](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/02_execution/01_chapter.html).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Actually, it is true that async is implemented via generators under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generators are a half-baked feature. There are many unresolved questions with them, and one of them is ability to define generator functions like you want.

For now, using a closure is the way to go.